# How can I persist sessions between a Ruby on Rails mongrel cluster and a Tomcat server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, tomcat, gwt, persistence

I have a hybrid Ruby on Rails/GWT system and need to persist session data between the two servers, such that when a user is logged into the Rails system they are "logged in" to the GWT/Tomcat system, and vice versa. Anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store your session data into a database which can be used by both systems.